# regarding the output format for semantic segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

While reading the semantic segmentation papers as well as their corresponding implementations, I found that some approaches use softmax while others use sigmoid for the pixel-level labeling.

For instance, with respect to [u-net paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0704/5f87709d0b7b998794e9fa912c0aba912281.pdf), the output is a feature map with two channels.

I have seen some implementations using softmax over these two channel outputs. I am not sure whether my following understanding is correct
or not?

For illustration purposes, the masked portion belongs to class 1 and the other part belongs to class 2. I only assume two class: masked or non-masked.

I use `xy` to represent the output map with shape (1, image_row,image_col,2). Then,`xy[1,0,0,0]` will represent the probability of pixel at (0,0) belonging to class 1 while `xy[1,0,0,1]` will represent the probability of pixel (0,0) belonging to class 2. In other words, `xy[1,row,col,0]+xy[1,row,col,1]=1`

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Semantic segmentation is just extended classification, where you perform classification of each pixel into the `n_classes`.

Let's say your input is an RGB image with size `(cols,rows,3)`, you pass a batch of such images sized `(batch_size, cols, rows, 3)` to the CNN.

After performing computations in the network graph, you will end up with a choice to have the last convolutional layer to have `n_outputs`.

### Binary segmentation (pixelwise yes / no )

---

Then you have can have `n_outputs = 1` and the output shape will be `(batch_size, cols, rows, 1)`. You later take the `sigmoid` activation use `binary_crossentropy` loss. Note that this only works for binary segmentation.

### MultiClass segmentation (pixelwise probability vector)

---

Then you have `n_outputs = n_classes` and the output shape will be `(batch_size, cols, rows, n_classes)`. Now comes the tricky part. You need to apply `softmax` to each pixel probability vector which generally involves permuting dimensions depending on the deep learning framework you are using. In this case you use `categorical_crossentropy` as it

In Keras you can

```
final_conv_out = Convolution2D(n_classes, 1, 1)(conv9)

x = Reshape((n_classes, rows*cols))(final_conv_out)
x = Permute((2,1))(x)

# seg is a pixelwise probability vector sized (batch_size, rows*cols, n_classes)
seg = Activation("softmax")(x)
```

Comment: In the binary segmentation, why use sigmoid activation instead of softmax?

Comment: @Claudio - In binary segmentation you can assume each pixel activation $p$ representing the probability of that pixel being *foreground*, thus making $1-p$, the probability of that pixel being background, therefore there is no need to have a separate variable for the same.